# Firebase change "DisplayName" only if password is correct

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm working on my Firebase application and I need some help with the logic because currently, it is not working as intended.

I'm trying to make it so that a logged-in user is only able to change their name if they type in the correct password.

With my current code it changes the name despite the toast message that the entered password was incorrect.

```
    /**
     * Update Name Only
     */
    private void updateDisplayNameOnly(){

        showProgress();

        AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider
                .getCredential(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail(), mConfirm.getText().toString());

        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().reauthenticate(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
                    {
                        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

                        UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdate = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                                .setDisplayName(mName.getText().toString())
                                //.setPhotoUri(Uri.parse("https://avatarfiles.alphacoders.com/862/86285.jpg"))
                                .build();

                        user.updateProfile(profileUpdate);

                        if (task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: User Profile updated");
                            hideProgress();

                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "NAME IS UPDATED XD XD XD", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            // RESTART APP FOR CHANGES
                        }

                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        hideProgress();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "NAME WAS NOT UPDATED 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

    }
```

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're issue could be that in your method you set `Task<Void>` to `Task<AuthResult>`. Trying modifying your code to the following:

```
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        if(task.isSuccessful())
        {
            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

            UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdate = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                    .setDisplayName(mName.getText().toString())
                    //.setPhotoUri(Uri.parse("https://avatarfiles.alphacoders.com/862/86285.jpg"))
                    .build();

            user.updateProfile(profileUpdate);

            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: User Profile updated");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "NAME IS UPDATED XD XD XD", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        } else {
            //Display what happens if you couldn't update the name
        }
        hideProgressDialog();
   });
```